# how to change the time of the image that appear after clicking app logo?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage

Whenever we click on the Iphone application...

An Image appears that stays for a while...

and after that it disappeared...

and the real window..i mean our programmed screen appears..

now I want that Image to stay for a while..

How to do this??

Comment: People want apps that start fast, they don't want to look at splash screens.

Comment: but I am just a developer...and unfortunately i don't have right to say anything :(...

Answer (score 0):

The image you're talking about is the splash screen, it's displayed until the OS loads your app's resources and launches it, the default name for it's image file in the bundle is Default.png. If you want it to be displayed for abit longer, you'll need to create an image view with the image, put it on the screen, and remove it after a while, probably in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method. something like

```
UIImageView *imageViewSplash = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:window.frame] autorelease]; 
imageViewSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
[self.viewController.view addSubview:imageViewSplash];
[imageViewSplash performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:2]; 
// change the '2' to some constants that represents for how many extra seconds you want the splash screen to be displayed
```

Comment: Which may result in apple rejecting it.

Comment: Thanks Zack...I am a new bie so din't know...i'll be thankful if you tell me what to do in that removeFromSuperview Method??

Comment: @Praveen unfortunately it's very unlikely that this will happen

Comment: oops?? will they reject it?? then what to do?? i must have to do that splash screen should be there for 5-6 seconds...:(

Comment: anyway...it's done by saviour [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];...but will apple reject it?

Comment: @rathodrc that remove from superview method will make the image disappear after the delay, you need to call it unless you want the image to stay there forever :)